# What is Full Coverage and No Coverage in Eclipse / Preferences / General / Editors / Text Editors / Annotations / stands for?

Tags: java, eclipse, preferences

What is 'Full Coverage' and 'No Coverage' in Eclipse / Preferences / General / Editors / Text Editors / Annotations / stands for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely those are coming from the [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/) plugin (code coverage analysis)

From the documentation at http://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/annotations.html :

> Source lines containing executable code get the following color code:
>
> - green for fully covered lines,
> - yellow for partly covered lines (some instructions or branches missed) and
> - red for lines that have not been executed at all.
>
> In addition colored diamonds are shown at the left for lines containing decision branches. The colors for the diamonds have a similar semantic than the line highlighting colors:
>
> - green for fully covered branches,
> - yellow for partly covered branches and
> - red when no branches in the particular line have been executed.
>
> ...
>
> The Eclipse preferences section *General* → *Appearance* → *Editors* → *Text Editors* → *Annotations* allows to modify the visual representation of coverage highlighting. The corresponding entries are:
>
> - Full Coverage
> - Partial Coverage
> - No Coverage